# Largest palindrome product - program not running, written solution but couldn't understand the problem

Tags: c++, c

I knew the code for finding out a palindrome in case of a given number, and I tried to generalize it for finding the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers like this :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,no,d,j,temp;
    int sum=0;
    clrscr();
for(i=1;i<1000;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<1000;j++)
    {       
           sum=0;
           no=i*j;
           temp=no;
           while(no>0)
           {
                 d=no%10;
                 sum=sum*10 + d;
                 no=no/10;
           }
           if(sum==temp)
           {
                 printf("number is Palindrome %d\n",sum);
           }
    }
}
getch();
}
```

But, I am not getting the solution, can anyone Help?

Comment: inside the second loop re-initialize sum to 0 every time

Comment: This might be a good moment to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). As a side note, this a really nice example of why should variables be created as close as possible to usages.

Comment: My TurboC++ sense is tingling, so here's a somewhat-standard warning. TurboC++ is ancient. It's going to be hard to find online support as most of what you will find will only go back as far as the C++98 or C99 Standards. (Note that the 98 and 99 refer to 1998 and 1999. Turbo C++ is older than that by about a decade). In addition it can be more difficult to adapt to the workforce because you've effectively been trained in the use of the bronze-tipped spear and your competition is using guns. I recommend augmenting your education with a book or two on and practice with modern C++.

Comment: Tauqeer, do not move the goalposts on a question once answers start rolling in. Prefer to ask one question per Question. If you find that the answer to you question raises more questions, ask more Questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int sum=0` should be inside the inner for loop, just before the line `no=i*j`:
For each new number, the value of the sum should be started from zero. If it is placed at the very beginning, it will take the value of `sum` generated from the previous `no` for all coming `no`.

If you place `sum=0` inside the `j` loop before `while` loop then for each new combination of `i*j` the sum will start from `0` and you will 100% get all the desired palindromes

Comment: can you tell me how do i find the largest palindrome, its too hard to find it manually, and i don't get that how to fit that code in this program.